# e mapache rewrite rule for subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running `XAMPP` on my local machine for my projects. I got a project and I place that project files under `c:\xampp\htdocs\newproject`. when I access this project in browser by `localhost/newprojet` it works fine. but all the images in source code are refrenced as `src="/images/del.jpg"` (starting with slash). As path starts with slash, so it looks for `images` folder under root directory which is `c:\xampp\htdocs`. if I place my `images` folder in this folder, all images load correctly. but if I put my `images` folder in `c:\xampp\htdocs\newproject`, the browser gives `404` for images. I know I've to use `apache rewrite rule` but I couldn't figure out some rule. I tried different rules in `.htaccess` file like:

```
DirectoryIndex default.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) images/$1 [NC,L]
```

and this one too:

```
DirectoryIndex default.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/images/(.*) images/$1 [NC,L]
```

but these are not working. can anyone help me regarding apache rewrite rules.

`NOTE: I cannot change source of images from /images/someimage.png to images/someimage.png`

here are contents of my `.htaccess` contents for reference. 
DirectoryIndex default.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule ^apis/creditCardCompany/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/CreditCardCompany.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/currency/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Currency.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/currentTax/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/CurrentTax.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/customer/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Customer.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/customerGroup/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/CustomerGroup.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/document/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Document.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/documentLine/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/DocumentLine.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/documentNumerator/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/DocumentNumerator.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/documentPayment/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/DocumentPayment.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/documentPaymentType/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/DocumentPaymentType.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/documentTax/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/DocumentTax.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/employee/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Employee.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/employeeGroup/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/EmployeeGroup.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/employeeStorage/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/EmployeeStorage.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/item/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Item.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/itemGroup/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ItemGroup.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/itemPricePerTaxRegion/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ItemPricePerTaxRegion.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/itemSaleAlert/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ItemSaleAlert.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/itemTag/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ItemTag.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/language/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Language.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/pos/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/PointOfSale.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/posType/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/PointOfSaleType.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/priceHistory/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/PriceHistory.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/storage/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Storage.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/supplier/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Supplier.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/tag/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Tag.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/taxRegion/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/TaxRegion.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/taxType/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/TaxType.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/workingHour/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/WorkingHour.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/customerTitle/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/CustomerTitle.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/creditType/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/CreditType.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/dbBrowser/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/DBBrowser.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/transaction/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Transaction.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/shvaReference/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ShvaReference.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/refund/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Refund.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getWorkingHour/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetWorkingHour.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getTransaction/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetTransaction.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getShvaReference/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetShvaReference.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getDocument/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetDocument.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getDocumentTax/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetDocumentTax.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getDocumentPayment/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetDocumentPayment.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getDocumentLine/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetDocumentLine.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/documentType/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/DocumentType.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/validationMethod/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ValidationMethod.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/generalParameter/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GeneralParameter.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/posParameter/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/PosParameters.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getRefund/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetRefund.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/buttonActionParameter/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ButtonActionParameter.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/buttonAction/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ButtonAction.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/buttonLayoutPage/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ButtonLayoutPage.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/buttonLayout/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ButtonLayout.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/object/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Object.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/company/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Company.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/dealer/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Dealer.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/organization/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Organization.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/specialPrice/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/SpecialPrice.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/message/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Message.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/electiveModule/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ElectiveModule.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/fixLabQuestionAnswerType/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/FixLabQuestionAnswerType.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/fixLabFixStatus/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/FixLabFixStatus.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/fixLabFixQuestion/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/FixLabFixQuestion.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/fixLabParameter/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/FixLabParameter.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/fixLabDocument/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/FixLabDocument.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/fixLabQuestionAnswer/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/FixLabQuestionAnswer.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/inventory/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Inventory.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/inventoryItem/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/InventoryItem.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/tempInventory/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/TempInventory.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/tempInventoryItem/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/TempInventoryItem.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/documentError/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/DocumentError.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/commission/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Commission.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/sort/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GridUserSort.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/user/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/User.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/userLogin/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/UserLogin.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/default/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ObjectDefault.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/label/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Label.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/dashboard/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Dashboard.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/companyLogo/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/CompanyLogo.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/modifierGroup/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ModifierGroup.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/modifier/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Modifier.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getPointsOfSaleData/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetPointOfSaleData.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/posLog/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/PosLog.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/getTable/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/GetTable.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/incometax/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/IncomeTaxOpenInterface.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/saronaMarket/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/SaronaMarket.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/sqlquerylog/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/SqlQueryLog.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^apis/servers/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Servers.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/shvaErrors/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/ShvaErrors.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apis/queries/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Queries.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^apis/softwareVersion/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/SoftwareVersion.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^apis/checkTaxChange/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/CheckTaxChange.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^apis/appModule/([^/]*)/([^/]*) appModule.php?action=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]



RewriteRule ^report/([^/]*)/([^/]*) entities/Report.php?name=$1&companyCode=$2


RewriteRule ^apis/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) handleAPIRequest.php?object=$1&command=$2&companyCode=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^device/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) handleDeviceRequest.php?object=$1&command=$2&companyCode=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) handleScriptRequest.php?scriptFile=$1&localeCode=$2&token=$3&companyCode=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^css/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) handleStyleRequest.php?cssFile=$1&localeCode=$2&token=$3&companyCode=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^upload/image/([^/]*) handleImageUpload.php?companyCode=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^data/merge/([^/]*)/([^/]*) handleDataMerge.php?language=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^data/import/([^/]*)/([^/]*) handleDataImport.php?language=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^data/export/([^/]*)/([^/]*) handleDataExport.php?language=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^excelData/export/([^/]*)/([^/]*) handleExcelDataExport.php?language=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^data/fastMerge/([^/]*)/([^/]*) fastHandleDataMerge.php?language=$1&companyCode=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^data/export/pdf handlePdfMaker.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^hello handleHello.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^image/barcode/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) handleBarcode.php?barcode=$1&scale=$2&type=$3&digits=$4 [NC,L]
```

all other rules are working absolutely fine. I've not added rule for `images` folder here as it mentioned already above.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
RewriteRule    ^$ images/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) images/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I used first rule after removing empty spaces. now when I open `localhost/newproject` it show the contents of `images` folder

Comment: make sure your rewrite is working ? Write your rules in <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>

Comment: I've some other rules too in .htaccess and they all are working fine. I will post contents of my .htaccess too